# Is there a way to run only an "external tool" in a JetBrains "run configuration"

Tags: command-line, ide, customization

Alle (or nearly all) "run configurations" in JetBrains IDEs provide an option to run an "external tool" as part of their execution. Is there a way to *only* run an external tool in a run configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need it... I can suggest trying the Bash Support plugin (http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4230?pr=idea) - it has a kind of 'generic' run configuration that can be used for running arbitrary executable. See if it works for you. But note that it's a third-party plugin JetBrains is not responsible for

Comment: Good suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't do the trick for me: it lacks understanding of PyCharm's variables (like `$ProjectFileDir$`).

Answer (score 0):

This has been a pain point for me for years. Here's my solution:

Run Configurations can be configured to invoke External Tools before launch, so the trick is to setup a run configuration that does absolutely nothing and then add your external tools to it.

**Example:** In WebStorm, I use an *npm* run configuration with the command set to *version*. Invoking this will cause all of the External Tool configurations in the *Before Launch* section to be executed (in order) before finally running `npm version`, which just generates output to the npm console.