# Can I run a shell alias or function as a JetBrains IDE "External Tool"?

Tags: bash, shell, alias, jetbrains-ide

In my `.bash_profile` I have

```
_func () {
   ... ${1} ${2}
}
alias func="_func"
```

and would like to be able to call `func` (or `_func`) in a JetBrains IDE "External Tool" (by specifying either as a "Program"). But when I do so I get

> Cannot run program "func"

Is there a way to run a shell alias or function as a JetBrains IDE "External Tool"?

---

I know there is [a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27850800/656912) with some limited support for something similar, but this does not support the IDE "macro" variables, as "External Tools" do.

Comment: You probably just have to make it an executable script instead of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you use must have an underlying executable. In this case it would be `/bin/bash` or similar, but Bash aliases are only available in the scope of a Bash shell.

As better solution would be to write a short Bash script and call that instead.

If you insist on using an alias, this will do it:

```
bash -l -c func
```

Comment: Looks like a Bash script is the way to go. I set up (finally) `~/bin` at the end of my `PATH` and put it there. `bash -l -c`, btw, doesn't work for me, but I think that's because of some oddities I have in it.